# .HTACCESS directory part of a URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I really couldn't understand how .htaccess works it's pretty complicated to me although I'm fine with Java/PHP anyways

I'm trying to rename the URL

http://mywebsite.com/olddir/index.php

to

http://mywebsite.com/newdir/index.php

Also want to rename for everything in the olddir so if its

http://mywebsite.com/olddir/process.php?do=this

it would be

http://mywebsite.com/olddir/process.php?do=this

Answer (score 2):

It is simple try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/olddir/(.*)$ /newdir/$1
```

This is quite basic you check if you have the olddir pattern and redirect than to the newdir.

If this does not work make sure that you have successfully installed modrewrite and that you have enabled rewriting with this line:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

If this not work yet check if you enabled changing settings in your directory directive there must be a line like this:

```
AllowOverride all
```

This line allows you to change several settings in .htaccess files.

Comment: Thanks but it hasn't worked for me

Comment: So you checked that modrewrite is installed and you have that `RewriteEngine On` in your .htaccess file and a `AllowOverride all` in your server configuration?

Comment: Yeah I did, I also tried using this //301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 olddir(.*) newdir/$1 but that would just spam newdir/newdir/newdir/newdir in the url

Comment: Your example points to `mod_alias` that is another module. You could try to add to my rule above a `[R=301,L]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `^` and `$` to your pattern:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/olddir(.*)$ /newdir/$1
```

Or using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^olddir/(.*)$ /newdir/$1 [L,R=301]
```